# Why FOR loop iterates only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've been reading a book for beginners, "First-Head HTML5 Programming" and there is this piece of code:

```
var movie2 = {
    title: "Forbidden Planet",
    genre: "Classic Sci-fi",
    rating: 5,
    showtimes: ["5:00pm", "9:00pm"]
  };

  function getTimeFromString(timeString) {
    var theTime = new Date();
    var time = timeString.match(/(\d+)(?::(\d\d))?\s*(p?)/);
    theTime.setHours( parseInt(time[1]) + (time[3] ? 12 : 0) );
    theTime.setMinutes( parseInt(time[2]) || 0 );
    return theTime.getTime();
  }


  function getNextShowing(movie) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    for (var i = 0; i < movie.showtimes.length; i++) {
      var showtime = getTimeFromString(movie.showtimes[i]);
      if ((showtime - now) > 0) {
        return "Next showing of" + movie.title + " is " + movie.showtimes[i];
      }
    }
   return null;
  }
```

Currently, if i call `getNextShowing(movie2)` it returns that next showing is at 5:00 PM.
 I changed the loops condition to "i **<=** movie.showtimes.length;" but it still runs only once and shows only 5:00 PM. 
 Loop iterates only once even if i rewrite this function:

```
function getNextShowing(movie) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    for (var i = 0; i <= movie.showtimes.length; i++) {
      var showtime = getTimeFromString(movie.showtimes[i]);
      return "Next showing of" + movie.title + " is " + movie.showtimes[i];
    }
   return null;
  }
```

Am i not getting something here?
At the first iteration i=0, loops runs and shows item of `showtimes` at index 0. After that it's i=1 and it should show item on index 1, no?

Shouldn't it run twice?

Comment: Think about what `return` does and you'll understand

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen oh

Answer (score 2):

You must have to know the detail of return keyword.

You can see  [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) for more detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If any poor idiot like me suffers from this "problem" - it's all because `return` ends the function execution. Jeeze..